# jQuery Accordion - Showing All Expanded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

UPDATE: Sorry - I was being a fool. display:block was left in the style for the div.

---

I have an ASP.Net page where I build up an HTML string that should be displayed as an accordion. This works, and the page renders the accordion however with all panels expanded.

Is there a way I can reset the panels to all collapsed after the HTML is written?

```
        System.Text.StringBuilder b = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        Condition[] conditions = SearchConditions(searchFor.Text);
        b.Append("<div id=\"ac1\" class=\"accordion\">");

        foreach (Condition c in conditions)
        {
            b.Append("    <h2>" + c.ConditionName + "<br /><span style=\"font-size:x-small\">" + c.Information + "</span></h2>" + Environment.NewLine) ;
            b.Append("    <div class=\"pane\" style=\"display:block; font-size:x-small\">" + Environment.NewLine);
            b.Append("        " + c.ConditionDescription + " <br /><br />" + Environment.NewLine);
            if (c.ConditionInstructions.Length > 0)
            {
                b.Append("        <div class=\"message error\">");
                b.Append("            <strong>Important:</strong><br />");
                b.Append("            " + c.ConditionInstructions + "");
                b.Append("        </div>");
                b.Append("        <br />");
            }
            b.Append("        <a href=\"#\">Add Condition</a>" + Environment.NewLine);
            b.Append("    </div>" + Environment.NewLine);   
        }
        b.Append("</div>");

        searchResults.Text = b.ToString();
```

searchResults.Text is an ASP:Literal control on the page.

Comment: Can you give us the code or a link?

Comment: jQuery accordians have a lot of logic to prevent multiple items from being open, it's very likely you aren't using it properly.

Comment: The accordion jquery plugin does not allow multiple panels to be open. Seems you don't use it correctly. Gotta show some code for us to see...

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have not imported jquery/css for accordian correctly. Verify, that you have included jquery ui accordion script and css in your page.

Comment: It does work as soon as I click one of the headings, all shrink except the one I clicked on, so I think the CSS is fine.

Comment: Are you calling your accordion within $(document).ready(function() { ... }

Comment: I'm running         $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#accordion").enable = true;

Comment: Sorry - I was being a fool.

display:block was left in the style for the div.